# How to make a Python Flask application to run as service in Linux vm

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python, I have created a python-flask application and put in to a Linux VM. Application is running fine, but if i close the terminal, I am not able access it, since the application is terminating.

I have gone through many Google answers, but nothing worked. I tried installing and configuring supervisor but got stuck somewhere. I created a file and put command - `nohup python /pathtomyscript` and even it was also not working.

Comment: read [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/) how to deploy.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Thanks ...But iam wondering why do we need a server again, if flask has already a builtin server embedded.

Comment: Do you want to create a Linux service (like with a script in `/etc/init.d`, which could be controlled with `service myflaskapp start|stop|restart|status`) specifically, or just launch your flask app in background?

Comment: Thanks Andrew for the response..I need to run the service even if i close the terminal, so that other can access the service without my interventions.I am not sure which of the above mentioned will be best suitable for this